# Does google adsense have background clickable ads?

Tags: adsense

I wonder if Adsense have background clickable ads. I mean ads which is background image, but clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Adsense doesn't provide such kind of ads because it causes accidental clicks, which is against the Adsense policy.